# Best practices for deploying an MVC application on IIS7

Tags: asp.net-mvc, deployment, iis-7, msdeploy

I'm not a web admin, and I'm new to IIS. So, I'm looking for advice.

My MVC application (e.g. fooapp) is the default application for my site (e.g. foo.bar). I used IIS Manager to add the site to IIS7. When I import the application, IIS Manager wants to put it in it's own directory (/foo), and tells me I shouldn't put it in the base (site) directory. This means that to get to my default MVC view, I have to enter the URL *`http://foo.bar/fooapp/`*. Needless to say, I want to get there via *`http://foo.bar/`*

I see 2 possible solutions:

1. Add a default page to the site directory that redirects to the MVC app.
2. Ignore the IIS admonition and load the app into the site directory.

My IIS7 knowledge is limited. I have played around with some options (such as HTTP Redirect). Since nothing changed,  I obviously don't understand what I'm doing.

Anyway, if there are some considered "best practices" and/or other suggestions, please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

Tbh, I'm not sure why the IIS manager is trying to convince you to add it as a sub app.. Maybe you just didn't do it right >_>

I've got a couple servers running with IIS7/7.5 and they have apps running in the root of the website.. No problem there :)

You might want to create a new website in IIS (right click on websites, choose "Add Web Site"), point the "Physical Path" directly to the folder your website's stored in, and set the `Host name` to whatever host you use (foo.bar ? :) )

This should work just fine )

In terms of deployment, if you use VS2010 I'd really recomment looking at Web Deploy.. It's a new addon written for IIS7, and allows one-click publish to IIS directly from VS2010. I'm using it on my site and it works flawlessly :)

Check out [Scott Hansellman's talk](http://live.visitmix.com/MIX10/Sessions/FT14) about it, or check it out in the [IIS website](http://www.iis.net/download/WebDeploy)

Comment: You are right that by default an application should reside in the root of the website. 
I guess the OP is already using MSDeploy (Web Deploy) because he talks about "import the application". This is only available if MSDeploy is installed as far as I know.